# reading data from excel file to gridView using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb

good day, im reading data from excel file and showing it to gridview. but errors says "The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file ''.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data."

what i have done:

1. give full access write to folder for IUSR, NETWORK_SERVICE, NETWORK, EVERYONE, USERS AND ADMIN

thank you in advance.

```
String filePath = txtBbSource.Text;
    String sheetName = txtSheetName.Text;

    string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;'";
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + sheetName + "$]", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    gridBalances.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: I have always had trouble accessing Excel via OLEDB.  If you are dealing with the newer .xlsx format, have a look at http://epplus.codeplex.com/ as an alternative.

Comment: This likely isn't permission related. Either file is in use by another user, process or your code already.

Comment: @EricJ. i will try epplus.codeplex maybe this week :)

Comment: @Serv this is my code sir serv. im very sure i close the excel. =)

Comment: Have you keep open Excel file while reading it with the program?

Comment: @Madhawas nope sir. i close the excel file while using my app

Comment: Try after giving access to everyone

Comment: @Madhawas yes done im done giving access permission (read/write) to everyone

Answer (score 0):

```
private void FillGrid(string FilePath, string Extension)
{

        string conStr = "";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        /*Add below Commented in Webconfig*/
         /*   <add name ="Excel03ConString"
     connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};
                     Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'"/>
          <!--connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};
                     Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'"/>-->
<add name ="Excel07ConString"
     connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};
                     Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'"/>
          * */
        switch (Extension)
        {
            case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                break;
            case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
                conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
                break;
        }
        conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, "Yes");
        OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
        OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();

        cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;
        try
        {
            int m = 1;
            //Get the name of First Sheet
            connExcel.Open();
            DataTable dtExcelSchema;

            dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            connExcel.Close();

            //Read Data from First Sheet
            connExcel.Open();
            cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";
            //oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
            //oda.Fill(dt);
            // connExcel.Close();
            DataTable myColumns = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, new object[] { null, null, SheetName, null });

            foreach (DataRow dtRow in myColumns.Rows)
            {
                if (dtRow["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString() == "Sr No" && dtRow["ORDINAL_POSITION"].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    m++;
                }
                else if (dtRow["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString() == "Task Name" && dtRow["ORDINAL_POSITION"].ToString() == "2")
                {
                    m++;
                }
            }
            /*column count in excel*/
            if (m < 2)
            {
                lblErrMsg.Visible = true;
                lblErrMsg.Text = "Selected file is not in required template format.";
                return;
            }
            oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
            oda.Fill(dt);
            connExcel.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblErrMsg.Visible = true;
            lblErrMsg.Text = "Selected file is not in required template format.";
            return;
        }

        DataTable dt_grd1 = new DataTable();
        DataRow drnewrow = null;


            //upload_plan = 1;
            foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt.Rows)
            {

                if (dtRow["Sr No"].ToString() == "" && dtRow["Task Name"].ToString() != "")
                {
                            dt_grd1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(string)));
                            dt_grd1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TASK_NAME", typeof(string)));    
                }

                    try
                    {
                        drnewrow = dt_grd1.NewRow();
                        drnewrow["ID"] = "";
                        drnewrow["TASK_NAME"] = dtRow["Task Name"].ToString();

                        dt_grd1.Rows.Add(drnewrow);

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //lblError.Visible = true;
                        ////lblError.Text = ex.Message;// "Authentication failed. Please try later.";
                        //lblError.Text = DataInteraction.Constants.EXCEPTION;
                    }
                }

            /*Using Linq Find same TASK_NAME present in Excel*/
            if (dt_grd1.Rows.Count >= 1)
            {

                var Taskresult = from c in dt_grd1.AsEnumerable()
                                 group c by new
                                 {

                                     TaskName2 = c.Field<dynamic>("TASK_NAME"),


                                 } into g
                                 where g.Count() > 1
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     g.Key.TaskName2,

                                     //  g.Key.Pin,
                                     Noofrec = g.Count()
                                 };

                if (Taskresult.ToList().Count > 0)
                {
                    lblErrMsg.Visible = true;
                    div_err_log.Visible = false;
                    lblErrMsg.Text = "Task with same Name not allowed.";
                    return;
                }
            }
            grdTaskDataCat1.DataSource = dt_grd1;
            grdTaskDataCat1.DataBind();

            /*End 13th Jan'17*/
            lblErrMsg.Visible = true;
            lblErrMsg.Text = "Please confirm the details uploaded and press save to complete the upload of Bid plan.";
            return;


}
```